# Is Ubuntu JeOS good for production purpose?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Actually I will want to use that JeOS for our webserver. Is it a good choice?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for piquing my interest. From the [Ubuntu website](http://www.ubuntu.com/products/whatisubuntu/serveredition/jeos):

> Ubuntu Server Edition JeOS (pronounced
>   "Juice") is an efficient variant of
>   our server operating system,
>   configured specifically for virtual
>   appliances. Currently available as a
>   CD-Rom ISO for download, JeOS is a
>   specialised installation of Ubuntu
>   Server Edition with a tuned kernel
>   that only contains the base elements
>   needed to run within a virtualized
>   environment.

It looks promising to me - I run several full Ubuntu 8.04 VMs so I'll certainly check it out. Why not just try it?

Answer (score 1):

Be aware that the kernel it installs is striped down to only have the stuff required for virtual machines, therefore you might have problems accessing the network from a real machine. (Note that the install-CD kernel isn't the same as the installed kernel as well).

If you can bypass that (IIRC I booted from the CD, and downloaded the normal server kernel and it all worked fine), then you end up with an absolutely minimal Linux system, but backed by the full Ubuntu repositories, so it's an excellent base for a server.

Also note minimal really means minimal - no cron by default for example.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it a good choice?

If you plan to run JeOS in a virtual machine, then yes, this is a good choice.